# Free uninitiailized pointer in C

Tags: c, free

If I dynamically allocated a space for a pointer, list this:

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

should I free a when the code is done? Thanks!

Comment: The space for the pointer isn't allocated dynamically, the `int` that it points to is. When the code is done, you should free it with `free(a);`.

Comment: 1. Don't cast `malloc`. 2. It is a good practice to free allocated memory and is always recommended, but it's not necessary if you use the pointer till the absolute end of the program.

Comment: Rule of thumb: anything that has been allocated by `malloc/calloc/realloc/` needs to be freed with `free` at some point.

Comment: I think I've got your question now. `a` is not uninitialized here. But the `int` _pointed_ by `a` is uninitialized. Yes you need to free `a` a some point.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Also `strdup`, `asprintf` and `vasprintf`.   Maybe others?

Comment: Why you shouldn't cast a malloc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @abelenky correct, but `asprintf` is a gcc extension, and `strdup` is posix.

Comment: Caution: the value passed to `free` must be *exactly the same* as was obtained from `malloc`, not one that has been, for example, incremented. The pointer's **value** is its only identity, as far as `free` is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
If you successfully malloc something is is correct to free it as well.

```
int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof int);
if (a != NULL)
{
    /* Do whatever you need to do with a */
    free(a);
}
else
{
    puts("the malloc function failed to allocate an int");
}
```

Comment: It is safe and well-defined to `free(NULL)`.

Comment: err..... that code looks like rather pointless, and the cast is not needed.

Comment: So for a linked list, as we know the first node of the list is empty, and we should free the first node at the end of the program??

Comment: @weather.   That is true in c++.

Comment: @EvilTeach ... and in C

Comment: C17 § 7.22.3.3 *If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.*

Comment: I'm considering to DV because the code here is really pointless.... 1. `free(NULL);` is a NOP anyway, 2. the whole code is pointless because the memory is freed right after being allocated, the code is not wrong, it's a bad example.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a little misunderstanding related to pointer.

Your title says:

> Free uninitialized pointer ...

and your code is

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The problem with this is that there is **no uninitialized pointer** in the code. The only pointer in the code is the variable `a` and it **is** initialized by the value returned by `malloc`.

Freeing an uninitialized pointer would be bad - example:

```
int *a;  // a is an uninitialized pointer

free(a);  // Real bad - don't do this
```

but since you actually initialize the pointer then - Yes, you must call free when your are done using the object/memory pointer `a` points to. It does not matter whether or not the pointed-to object (aka memory) has been assigned a value.

The general rule: For each call of `malloc` there must be a call of `free`

(Exception: If your program terminates, you don't need to call `free`)

Answer (score 3):

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
if (a) 
{
    /* a is now valid; use it: */
    *a = 1 + 2 + 3;
    printf("The value calculated is %d\n", *a);
}

/* Variable A is done being used; free the memory. */
free(a);  /* If a failed to be allocated, it is NULL, and this call is safe. */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

> should I free a when the code is done?

The question should be

> Must I free a when the code is done?

And the answer is YES. A `malloc` must be accompanied by a a `free` statement.

```
free(a);
```